# Need help about iteratively guessing game

Tags: c++

I'm new at coding, i made a small game. But program turns it self off after you answer true or false. But i want to make this program iteratively. I mean after you guess it, program should restart.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
    
using namespace std;
    
int main()
{
    int secretnum;
    int guess;
    int guesscount = 0;
    int guesslimit = 3;
    bool outofguesses = false;
    bool success = false;
    bool success2 = true;
    
    do {
        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> secretnum;
        system("cls");
        do {
            if (guesscount < guesslimit) {
                cout << "Enter your guess: ";
                cin >> guess;
                guesscount++;
            }
            else {
                outofguesses = true;
            }

        } while (secretnum != guess && !outofguesses);

        if (outofguesses) {
            cout << "You lose." << endl;
            success = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "You win." << endl;
            success = true;
        } 
    } while (success == success2);

    if (success == true) {
         guesscount = 0;
         guesslimit = 3;
         outofguesses = false;
         success = false;
         success2 = true;
    }
    else if (success == false)
         guesscount = 0;
         guesslimit = 3;
         outofguesses = false;
         success = false;
         success2 = true;

    system("pause>0");
}
```

Here is my code. I added "bool success", "bool success2" (success is false, success2 is true). When you guess it, program set success true and as you can see i added a code "while (success == success2);"

But after that -I mean you end game correct or wrong- this last part of code doesn't refresh/reset the "guesslimit". How can i fix that??

Comment: Why would you expect anything to continue looping after you exit the loop?  And unrelated, but your indentation is misleading in the `else if` at the end.

Comment: All your reset code is outside of the main `while` loop. Put it in there. You can move the lines after `main() {` and before `do {` to right after the `do {`. And delete all the lines after the `while`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is getting very convoluted because you are using many unneeded variables. The variables `success`, `success2` and `outofguesses` are all unnecessary.

If you use infinite loops and use an explicit `break` to break out of an infinite loop when necessary, the code is much cleaner and it is easy to restart the game:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

constexpr int GUESS_LIMIT = 3;

int main()
{
    //one loop iteration represents a whole game
    for (;;) //infinite loop, equivalent to while(1)
    {
        int secret_num;
        int guess_count = 0;

        cout << "Enter a number: ";
        cin >> secret_num;

        system("cls");

        //one loop iteration represents a single guess
        for (;;)
        {
            int guess;

            cout << "Enter your guess: ";
            cin >> guess;
            guess_count++;

            if ( guess == secret_num )
            {
                cout << "You win." << endl;
                break; //break out of infinite loop
            }

            if ( guess_count == GUESS_LIMIT )
            {
                cout << "You lose." << endl;
                break; //break out of infinite loop
            }
        }

        cout << "\n\nRestarting game...\n\n";
    }
}
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that you have no code for handling bad input. If the user provides bad input such as "g" instead of a number, then your program will start misbehaving. Therefore, it is safer to check for input failure, and to handle it properly.

The easiest form of handling bad input is to simply exit the program. In order to do so, you can change the code

```
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> secret_num;
```

to:

```
cout << "Enter a number: ";
cin >> secret_num;
if ( cin.fail() )
{
    cout << "Input error!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You can do the same with the lines:

```
cout << "Enter your guess: ";
cin >> guess;
```

If you don't won't the program to exit on bad input, then you could make a loop which continues running until the user enters valid input, for example like this:

```
for (;;)
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> secret_num;

    if ( !cin.fail() )
        break;

    cout << "Input error, try again!\n";

    //discard remainder of line
    cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n' );

    //clear stream flags
    cin.clear();
}
```